# How do I grab all the content from within [url] including square brackets and match group 1 and 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, bbcode

I have this regular expression

```
/\[url=(?:&quot;)?(.*?)(?:&quot;)?\](.*?)\[\/url\]/mi
```

and these blocks of text

```
[url=/someurl?page=5#3467]First[/url][postquote=true]
[url=/another_url/who-is?page=4#3396] Second[/url]
Some text[url=/another_url/who-is?page=3][i]3[/i] Third [/url]
```

and the regex works great at extracting the urls and text between the urls

Match 1

```
1.  /someurl?page=5#3467
2.  First
```

Match 2

```
1.  /another_url/who-is?page=4#3396
2.  Second
```

Match 3

```
1.  /another_url/who-is?page=3
2.  [i]3[/i] Third
```

The problem happens when I use the same regex from above to try to extract the url from this text

```
This is some text [url=https://www.somesite.com/location/?opt[]=apples]Link Name[/url]
```

Match 1

```
1.  https://www.somesite.com/location/?opt[
2.  =apples]Link Name
```

Notice the `=apples]` in the second match. What I need is the matched first match to include that in the url like

1. https://www.somesite.com/location/?opt[]=apples
2. Link Name

I have tried many modifications to this regex and no go so far, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: If it is RoR, see [BBCode for Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506002/bbcode-for-ruby-on-rails).

Comment: yes ruby on rails and I am using BBCode but this question is just plain regex though

Comment: See http://rubular.com/r/NpsJ554IOi

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thats great but I need match 1 and 2 and you have 1 2 and 3. Can you remove one please?

Comment: @Trace It is impossible. The second group is technical to ensure recursion.

Comment: Wait I might be able to use this

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Worked, if you want to add this to a question I can accept

Comment: Just thought: what if you have `]...[` in the string? It won't work then. Well, maybe Casimir's approach is worth more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby regex has the duplicate named capture feature. With this feature, you can handle the two cases easily *(the one with `&quote;` and the other)*. You don't have to use a recursive pattern since I doubt that [] can be nested in the query part of a url:

```
/\[url=(?:&quote;(?<url>[^&]*(?:&(?!quote;)[^&]*)*)&quote;|(?<url>[^\s\]\[]*(?:\[\][^\s\]\[]*)*))\](?<text>.*?)\[\/url\]/mi
```

the url is in the named group *url* and the content between tags is in the named group *text*.

in a more readable format:

```
/

\[url=
(?:
    &quote; (?<url> [^&]* (?:&(?!quote;)[^&]*)* ) &quote;
  |
    (?<url> [^\s\]\[]* (?:\[\][^\s\]\[]*)* )
)
\]
(?<text>.*?)\[\/url\]

/mix
```

Comment: this works good but I do not need the `text` and `url` I just need 1 and 2 matched like my example

Comment: can you help remove the text and url and only have match 1 and 2 like my example?